# Sort an array of objects by property of second element in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Searching many examples I didn't manage to solve my case. I have an array
that should be sorted by `author`. My attempt did nothing. What is the right expression?

```js
var array = [
  ["ifke", {
    "title": "secure",
    "author": "admin"
  }],
  ["lottery", {
    "title": "The lo",
    "author": "anton"
  }],
  ["short-content", {
    "title": "Short Content",
    "author": "scott"

  }],
  ["ziddler", {
    "title": "The Fiddler",
    "author": "herman"

  }]
];


array.sort((a, b) => a[1].author - b[1].author)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Ok before even attempting to answer, may I ask why your data is structured that way? It's awful. Because if this isn't just homework assignment, then I'd strongly advice re-thinking the way you store data

Comment: Try `array.sort((a, b) => a[1].author.localeCompare(b[1].author))`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The data structure comes from an [import function loading markdown files into a JSON] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-json) object. Now my target is to return this sorted as described.

Answer (score 2):

A working solution using .sort method of an array and using localeCompare method to sort based on the strings

```js
var array = [
 [ "ifke", {
    "title": "secure",
    "author": "admin"
  }],
  ["lottery", {
    "title": "The lo",
    "author": "anton"
  }],
  ["short-content", {
    "title": "Short Content",
    "author": "scott"
  
  }],
  ["ziddler", {
    "title": "The Fiddler",
    "author": "herman"

  }]
];

array.sort((a,b) => a[1].author.localeCompare(b[1].author));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but you need to use a differet way of comparing. The subtraction operator on non-numeric strings always yields `NaN`, which is useless for comparison.

You could use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), which reutrns `1`, `0`, or `-1`:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a[1].author.localeCompare(b[1].author))
```

Comment: Dupe............